Conexión SSH desde Visual Studio Code Desde un MacOS
Cuando intento establecer la conexión desde un Mac con un ordenador remoto, me da el error: Could not establish connection to "IP": No route to host. Cuando intento la conexión desde el terminal del Mac, sí se establece la conexión SSH. El error lo tengo dentro de Visual Studio Code.
He arreglado el fichero de configuración poniendo de forma explícita el puerto y el fichero de la clave, pero no he tenido resultado alguno, sigue dando el mismo error.

Parece ser un problema conocido: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/228862

Perfecto, ya me funciona. Muchas Gracias.

Ahora puedes crear una respuesta dando solución al problema, para beneficios de otros usuarios. Además, ganaras puntos.
